# Is this a valid quadratic equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The quadratic equation is as follows;

$$x^2-\sqrt{2}x+1/2^2=0                 \qquad\qquad(1)$$

Here,$ a = 1$; $b=-\sqrt{2}$;$ c=1/4$

The discriminant, $(b^2 - 4ac)=1$, which is a perfect square;

So the roots of the quadratic equation, should be rational and unequal as given on page no. 84 of the book "HIGHER ALGEBRA BY H. S. HALL AND S. R. KNIGHT".

But the roots of the quadratic equation "(1)" are IRrational and unequal.

Comment: `b=√2` There is no $x$ term in the equation you posted. Did you mean $-\sqrt{2} x$ maybe?

Comment: THANKS DXIV FOR POINTING THE MISTAKE.

Comment: `So the roots of the quadratic equation, should be *rational* and unequal` That only applies if the *coefficients* are rational. In this case, they are not.

Comment: just move the term on the right hand side over to the left, and include it in the c term, then it obviously has the form $ax^2+by+c=0$.  Then by definition it is a quadratic equation.

Comment: ^* I meant $ax^2+bx+c=0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There really are two different questions here:

> Is this a... quadratic equation?

Yes, certainly -- it's a polynomial equation of degree 2, which is the definition of a quadratic equation.

> Why does it have irrational roots, even though the discriminant is $1$?

The property "a quadratic equation whose discriminant is a positive perfect square will have two rational solutions" is only true for polynomials with *rational* coefficients.  This polynomial has irrational coefficients, so that property simply doesn't apply.  The quadratic formula still gives the solutions, though.

Answer (score 0):

A quadratic expression is a polynomial of degree $2$.

No tricks. No exceptions. (I think)

Your equation is $\displaystyle x^2-\sqrt{2}x+\frac{1}{2^2}=0$.

In standard form, this is $\displaystyle x^2 - \sqrt{2}x+\frac{1}{4}=0$.

So yes, it is a quadratic equation, because each side can clearly can be written as a polynomial with degree less than or equal to $2$.

---

Even though the discriminant is $1$, we have that $b=\sqrt{2}$.

Therefore, the solutions are $\displaystyle x = \frac{\sqrt{2} \pm 1}{2}$.

For this particular reason, the property holds for equations with rational coefficients.

Comment: sorry, he wrote that originally. @dxiv

Answer (score 0):

It is certainly a quadratic equation. The solutions of $Ax^2+Bx+C=0$ with $A\ne 0$ are $$x=\frac {-B\pm \sqrt {B^2-4AC}\;}{2A}.$$ So if $A,B$ and $\sqrt {B^2-4AC}\;$ are all rational then $x$ is rational.

However if $A$ and $\sqrt {B^2-4AC}$ are rational but $B$ isn't, then $x$ isn't either. Because then $-B/2A$ is irrational and $\sqrt {B^2-4AC}\;/2A$ is rational , so their sum or difference cannot be rational.

I suggest you check the text again. It may be that on page 84, $A,B,C$ were all  assumed to be rational.